# Sub list is not binding to ListView grouping in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding, binding, listviewgroup

I'm implementing listview grouping in xamarin forms to display the list within a listview. I need to show one header and a list under the header.

Models:

```
public class ActivityHistoryDetails
    {
        public string EventDate { get; set; }
        public List<History> History { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm binding a list of "ActivityHistoryDetails" type to the listview.

Now I'm able to display only the header with this code. Sub Lists are not binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your needs, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#related-links).

According to your code, I wrote a runnable, minimized example for your reference, you can refer to it to modify your code.

Here is the `History` class:

```
public class History
{
    public string ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneComment { get; set; }
    public string EventRptId { get; set; }
    public string EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventTime { get; set; }
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public History(string zoneId, string zoneComment, string eventRptId, string eventDate, string eventTime, string eventDescription, int storeId)
    {
        ZoneId = zoneId;
        ZoneComment = zoneComment;
        EventRptId = eventRptId;
        EventDate = eventDate;
        EventTime = eventTime;
        EventDescription = eventDescription;
        StoreId = storeId;
    }
}
```

Here is the `ActivityHistoryDetails` class:

```
public class ActivityHistoryDetails : List<History>
{
    public string EventDate { get; set; }
    public static IList<ActivityHistoryDetails> All { private set; get; }

    public ActivityHistoryDetails(string EventDate)
    {
        this.EventDate = EventDate;
    }

    static ActivityHistoryDetails() 
    {
        List<ActivityHistoryDetails> Groups = new List<ActivityHistoryDetails>
        {
            new ActivityHistoryDetails ("aaa")
            {
                new History("test","test","test","test","test","test",1),
                new History("test1","test1","test1","test1","test1","test1",2)
            },
            new ActivityHistoryDetails ("bbb")
            {
                new History("test2","test2","test2","test2","test2","test2",3),
                new History("test3","test3","test3","test3","test3","test3",4)
            }
        };
        All = Groups;
    }
}
```

Use `GroupedView.ItemsSource = ActivityHistoryDetails.All;` for data binding.

The xaml code is the same as the code you provided.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: As long as it is a list, it does not have to be static.

Comment: According to your code, is your res a List<ActivityHistoryDetails>?

Comment: Then we need to bind List<ActivityHistoryDetails>, then we can directly bind to xaml.

Comment: You can take a look at my code. I adjusted it based on your code, even xaml did not modify it. "aaa" and "bbb" in the screenshot are groupings, which correspond to "EventDate"

Comment: According to my code, Groups are multiple ActivityHistoryDetails data, and the EventDate in ActivityHistoryDetails is the head of the dynamic array. You can even copy my code completely, just add the value of Groups correctly to bind a dynamic array.